# Why my la-liga tag wiki edit was rejected?

Tags: discussion, tags

The first time I've added the tag wiki for [la-liga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-liga), I've irresponsibly copied introductory information from wikipedia (although I've added the link to the article, it still didn't add much value to the site). This edit was rightfully rejected.

But then I understood my mistake and added my own content to the tag wiki, but it still was [rejected by @CodeNewbie and @Nij](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13465). Here yo can see the full tag wiki suggestion for [la-liga](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/la-liga):

> [La Liga](http://www.laliga.es/en), officially the Primera División, is the highest level of
>   football league system of Spain. Leading the [UEFA member association
>   ranking](http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/uefarankings/country/season=2013/index.html) table since 2012/13 season, La Liga is considered as one
>   of the [top 5 European leagues](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15773/who-is-the-fifth-big-five-in-european-football-leagues/15778#15778).
>
> The most successful clubs (with titles won: La Liga, CL, EL) from La
>   Liga are listed below:
>
> - Real Madrid (33, 12, 2)
> - Barcelona  (24, 5, 0)
> - Atlético Madrid (10, 0, 2)
> - Athletic Bilbao (8, 0, 0)
> - Valencia (6, 0, 1)
> - Real Sociedad (2, 0, 0)
> - Sevilla (1, 0, 5)
> - Deportivo La Coruña (1, 0, 0)
> - Real Betis (1, 0, 0)

So, do you agree that this tag wiki edit had to be rejected?

Answer (score 2):

A tag wiki should briefly describe the topic and explain how the tag is properly applied. The first paragraph does this to a limited extent, but not by enough to overcome the following issue.

Histories, records and trivia are not relevant to either task. At best a link to such material should be included. The summary version was no better than the wholesale copying of the table in the first attempt.

Comment: I read your post as "nothing is better than something".

Comment: You should read it as "nothing is better than **pointless or unhelpful** somethings **that ignored clear guidelines**".

Comment: It's very **biased** and not nice of you to call my whole post with some interesting basic information, where I've clearly put significant effort, pointless. Please read the [very first paragraph of SE network model](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/stackexchange). I remember I've already suggested it to you once.

Comment: If you're going to get emotionally invested, I'm not interested. Write a tag wiki that follows the guidelines, like the excerpt *that I voted to approve*, and put it through the system. Good day.